# How can I simplify the signature when documenting template class member functions with Doxygen?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

```
template <typename a, typename b, typename c, typename d>
class Aclass {
    template <typename e>
    void foo() {
    }
};
```

Documenting foo gives me a result something like this:

```
void Aclass<a, b, c, d>::foo()
```

With more template parameters the member function's class scope becomes more and more tedious to read. Is there a way to shorten the output to say `Aclass` for every member function?